# Changing cppcheck alloc/free functions names

Tags: c, cppcheck

I've a source code that was written with wrappers to dynamic memory allocation.

something like:

```
wrapper_free(void *ptr);
wrapper_malloc(size_t size);
```

this was done to ensure portability, and as the code is third-party the problem is to fix the bugs and not rewrite it all.

I want to verify the code with cppcheck, but since cppcheck don't resolve function calls, no error in memory allocation will be found.

There is a way to change de the cppcheck functions for memory allocation/free so it will check the wrappers instead of standard functions ?

Comment: How are `wrapper_free` and `wrapper_malloc` defined?

Comment: For what I can see, it is a define of a define of a define ... switched with ifdefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible using cppcheck config files, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<def>
 <resource>
  <alloc>wrapper_malloc</alloc>
  <dealloc>wrapper_free</dealloc>
 </resource>
</def>
```

Comment: +1 Do you know, how to [re-define an identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22168480/2932052)?