# make cppcheck skip the PACKAGE definition

Tags: c++, vcl, static-code-analysis, cppcheck, language-extension

I'm using the GUI version of cppcheck 1.64 for static code analysis on C++-Builde-6 code. For DLL exports and imports, the definition of `PACKAGE` is necessary:

```
/// A dialog exported from a BPL (a VCL-specific kind of DLL)
class PACKAGE MySharedDialog {

public:
    // lots of methods to-be checked

private:
    // lots of methods to-be checked

    // lots of members

};
```

Cppcheck stops when it encounters `PACKAGE` because it doesn't know what it means:

> The code 'class PACKAGE TAppInfoDialog {' is not handled. You can use -I or --include to add handling of this code.

...and this of course means that the entire class isn't checked. If I could make cppcheck **simply ignore the `PACKAGE`** "keyword", it would do *exactly* the right thing, but how to do it? Including its original definition via include path, seems to be not an option: cppcheck then tells me **a lot about headers** of the VCL framework **I cannot change**...

[The manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf) does not describe an option to do it, Google doesn't help, SO does not have an answer yet.

In the cppcheck issue tracker, I found the analogous problem [#4707 (Microsoft 'abstract' and 'sealed' extension for class) – cppcheck](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/4707). Here the lead developer suggests to create a file and (pre-?)include it to the cppcheck run, but I'm using the GUI version and there is no option to include a single file. So I tried to add a directors to the include section of my project options (an XML file), then I edited the corresponding line to a file specification, but that's clearly nonsense, because this section contains *include paths*.

What can I try next?

Comment: It is open source, everybody is waiting for your patch.

Comment: @HansPassant :) I hope this is only a joke, and there is already an option. For example using a define that cppcheck is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to add the definition of `PACKAGE` (being empty) to the project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="1">
    <defines>
        <define name="PACKAGE=" />
    </defines>    
</project>
```

This solution I finally found in this small but valuable project file description at the project repo [cppcheck/gui/projectfile.txt at master · danmar/cppcheck · GitHub](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/gui/projectfile.txt)

Comment: Yes to skip PACKAGE, defining it to be empty is the best solution.

Comment: @DanielMarjamäki Thanks for the official statement :) - Is there a way to centralize such project definitions (by including, via config)?